# Getting AJAX error when returning data

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am having a problem where I am always getting back errors on my ajax call from jquery. It is only happening in the index.php program. I have tried to simplify the problem: Here is the code from index.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function createSympathyData() {
$.ajax({
url: "buildsympathydata.php",
type: 'post',
success: function (jqxhr, status, errorMsg){     
     console.log(jqxhr, status, errorMsg);
    $('#sympathy_target').append(jqxhr);
    },
    error: function(jqxhr, status, errorMsg) {
        console.log(jqxhr, status, errorMsg);
            },
    })
};
$(document).ready(function (){
$('#sympathy_target').each(function() { 
createSympathyData();
});   
});
</script>
```

Php program - buildsympathydata.php:

```
<?php
$buildhtml = 'test data';
echo $buildhtml; ?>
```

Always returns error with alert(jqxhr) = [object Object], alert(status)=error, alert(errorMsg) = blank alert. Using jquery 1.6.1. Not having any problems anywhere else using jquery and ajax. These errors appear on both my localhost and my live website(FTP the program, tested, then restored original). Any ideas would be greatly appreciated as I have been trying to resolve this issue for a couple of days. Thanks, Danny

Comment: Please don't abuse the `alert()` like that. Log the debugs in the console. D:

Comment: and status?? `alert(status);`

Comment: in the error block rather add this `console.log(jqxhr, status, errorMsg);`

Comment: Why on earth have you named the parameters for the `success` callback function that?

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses. I have modified alerts to use console log and now getting: [object Object] "error" "". The buildsympathydata.php is processing as I placed a debugbreak in the php code(localhost), ran index.php in firebug/chrome debug, and the ajax was sent to the localhost and echo back, but keeping getting error on the returned data. This should be very simple process as my ajax calls work rest of my website. Original buildsympathydata.php has more logic, but simplified to get ajax working(added the alerts before for testing). Just makes no sense. Thanks for assistancing, Dan

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$.post(
   "buildsympathydata.php",{data:random}
).done(function(data)
{
$('#sympathy_target').append(data);
});
```

jqxhr is object top code is cool
please fill data as random e.g `math.random()`